# Java Classes versus C++ Classes

Tags: java, c++, android, class-design

I just started learning to develop for the Android, and I come from a strictly C++ background. I found that Java does not support Multiple Inheritance, but do we really have to create a seperate .java file for every new Activity?

I have a TabActivity, with 3 more Activitys that make up the tabs. I want to create a List View on one of the tabs, but I am starting to get confused. Do I need to make another .java file that extends ListActivity? I can see even a relatively small application becoming extremely large if I am going to need to create a seperate .java file for every activity.

*SIDE NOTE*

If I want to add the ListView to one of my tabs, how would I do that? Nothing I have found thus far mentions how to add new activities to other Activities.

Comment: http://www.behestee.com/blog/?p=48 is that the best way to do what I mentioned in the side not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers give good points about interfaces and that is probably more what you are looking for.  However, for further information, no you don't have to create a new .java file for every new class, there are [alternatives](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).  However, keep in mind that more classes is not necessarily a bad thing.  Your options are...

**Nested Class:**

```
public class A {

    public/private class B {

    }

}
```

Instances of B can access private variables of A but cannot be constructed without an instance of A (this is an approach often used for button handlers, etc.)

**Nested Static Class:**

```
public class A {

    public/private static class B {

    }

}
```

Instances of B cannot access private variables of A but they do not require an instance of A in order to be constructed.  Instances of B can be instantiated anywhere if B is declared public, or only in A's methods if B is declared private.

**Anonymous Class:**

```
public class A {

    private void setupLayout() {

        ...
        button.addClickListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerfored(ActionEvent e)
            {
                handleClick();   
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This strange syntax creates a class that has no name and functions the same as a nested class (e.g. can access private variables).  It's an alternative form of writing nested classes that is sometimes shorter but leads to very strange syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance on abstract or normal classes but on interfaces only.

What you can do is create abstract classes that extends a particular `Activity` and keep creating abstract classes until you have a class that inherit all your activity features.

Alternatively, is have a class that inherits multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an IDE to do this, the overhead of creating lots of file is much smaller.

However there are a few ways to have many classes in the same file. This includes a) using inner/nested classes b) anonymous classes c) enums d) package local classes.

The only thing you cannot do is easily if spread the definition of a class across multiple files.

Comment: *The only thing you cannot do is easily if spread the definition of a class across multiple files.* - which is good actually.

Comment: @bestsss: That's just something imposed by the language it does not make it good (or bad). Understandably in the normal situation spreading your code around is not a good idea but there are situation where it can be useful to do so and putting arbitrary restrictions in the language will seem counter productive to a C++ programmer.

Comment: @Martin, Classes can use abstract super classes, delegation and helper methods to spread the code around. It becomes more than one class that way but if you want to take a large class in single and turn it into multiple files you can (provided you add classes to do it)

Comment: @Martin, if you really need so huge class, there is a design flaw; there are plenty of ways to delegate execution, functionality w/o having hundreds of fields. It can be argued also that the multiple inheritance can improve performance (due to locality and lack of extra indirections) but in practice is creates mostly confusion and hard to maintain code.

Comment: @bestsss: There are lots of ways of achieving everything. But having arbitrary rules built into the language just to prevent inexperienced programmers from being silly is just that (an arbitrary restriction). I totally agree that in the `normal` situation this will usually be a design flaw or can be handled in a better way, but there will always be an out-layer where this arbitrary decisions makes the code less readable (and giving an experienced developer the prerogative to do something intelligent may have been nicer).

Comment: Good practice/Code review and team agreement to deviating from the norm would in my opinion be better than arbitrary rules.

Comment: @Martin, good practice, itself, takes some practice and code reviews are extra cost (basically), having some establish hard rules is ok, imo. I've been doing assembler before java. So I can appreciate freedom to do whatever you might need but after a couple of weeks (doing java) I also appreciated how elegant it was. I still insist it's a good language decision.

Answer (score 1):

> Java does not support Multiple Inheritance

Workaround is you use interfaces

> but do we really have to create a seperate .java file for every new Activity

No, if your activity can be done in an existing class or can be sub classed in an existing class. Java is built around creating classes for each activity.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance. But it does allow implementing multiple `interface`s. You don't need to create a seperate file for each `class` (though it's a good practice). You can encapsulate sub-classes in the main `class` of your file.

`ListView` can be simply `extend`ed and you can use the corresponding extended class in the xml etc.

Answer (score 0):

Java does kind of support multiple inheritance, if you just make the base classes abstract and call them `interface` instead of `class`.

Comment: That's not the same thing though, not by a long shot.

Comment: `abstract` base class and `interface` are different.

Comment: An interface (in Java) has no implemented methods. An abstract class (in C++) has at least one pure virtual function, but might have virtual functions that aren't pure, and might have implemented functions (including the pure virtual ones, for that matter). Similarly an abstract class in Java can have implemented methods. So "abstract" is the wrong term, but the basic idea is there, if you can turn your "extra" C++ base classes into interfaces, then you can migrate the design to Java (well, that aspect of it). If you can't, you have to change the design.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare a `ListView` in XML and call it in the `Activity`, no need to have a separate `ListActivity`, just for `ListView`. It's when your whole `Activity` is a `ListView`.

And as per the concerns about more classes, it's not a bad thing. More classes means more object oriented, not strictly though (Everything has a limit).
Multiple Inheritence was considered not good due to problem of diamond of death. So the work-around was to use `Pure Virtual Classes` known as `Interface` in Java (Interface means a normal class in Objective-C though).
I suggest you to read [HeadFirst Java second edition](http://www.headfirstlabs.com), for better grip on terminology and their use. It's a good book for beginners.